# Cannot resolve namespace std in Android Studio

Tags: c++, android-studio

I have a native library for an Android app. When I load the entire C++ project in **Android Studio**, some errors are thrown by the IDE saying:

> cannot resolve namespace std and cannot find any C++ headers.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
```

For all of the above code, `fstream`, `iostream`, etc is being marked red and shows cannot find. Any workaround to fix the above issue?

Comment: Did you install NDK? Looks like you don't have NDK installed

Comment: Where did you expect `namespace std` to come from? The first problem is that you're missing headers. Obviously, that also causes secondary problems such as missing the _contents_ of those headers, but those problems disappear when you fix the root cause.

Comment: @Asesh, NDK is installed